# sed not substituting as expected

Tags: regex, sed

I need to substitute each \n in a line with "\n (double quote followed by newline).

This should work. But it does nothing. Reports no error either. Any clues anyone?

```
sed -i 's/\n/\"\n/' filename
```

before, the file contains:

```
line 1
line 2
```

after, it contains the exact same.

Thanks

- Balt

Comment: I should add: the lines are delimited by newlines, and I also tried this: sed -i 's/\n/\"\n/g' filename with the same effect, no error, no change to the file.

Answer (score 5):

A line can't contain `\n`, because `\n` is the delimiter between lines. `sed` operates on a single line at a time, and the newline is not included in it.

If you want to put a character before the end of each line, use the `$` regexp:

```
sed -i 's/$/"/' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
sed -i 's/$/"/' filename
```

used `$` to denote end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk '{$0=$0"\""}1' filename
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what does the `1` mean at end of the ACTION?

Comment: When an test is true (as 1 always is) do default action `print $0`  So you can use`1 {print $0}` or only `1`